# Finding a combination in Excel based on the two values

Tags: excel

I have the below data.

```
Category  Group
Cat1      Group1
Cat2      Group2
Cat3      Group3
Cat3      Group1
Cat1      Group2
Cat2      Group3
```

I would like to display the data in the below format

```
Category  Group1  Group2  Group3
Cat1      TRUE            TRUE
Cat2              TRUE    TRUE
Cat3      TRUE
```

Can some one help me with the formula in excel?

Thanks,
Siva.

Answer (score 0):

Given a data setup as shown, in cell E2 and copied over and down is this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1)>0,TRUE,"")
```

[image: tigeravatar example for user2429233]